# ios ui object check for text property

Tags: ios

I need to check if some object has text property. For example it can be an `UIButton` or an `UILabel`. But there is an issue between properties that display text for an `UIButton` and for an `UILabel`.

This is the difference:

For an `UIButton` we set text using `setTitle:` method, but for an `UILabel` we using another one named `setText:`

What I need to do with this:

I need to get all subviews and if these subviews have text property I need to change this property value with some text.

So of course I can check class of object and setup needed property, but maybe we have another approach to do it without checking class of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (id item in [self.view subviews])
{
    if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(text)])
        [item setText:@"text"]; // change text for UILabel
    else if ( [item respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitle:forState:)])
        [item setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // change text for UIButton
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. this is really work solution. Unfortunately, I understand that we can't using just one property for setting text cause of differences in ui objects property. but this one of few solutions that's working great.